# MS Access - SQL/VBA SELECT SUM - Can not execute a select query #ERROR

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to total up the amount of hours lead time on a job card to be assigned to a variable so it can be used later in a job scheduling code.. but getting a run time error and I don't know why

SUM of OpleadTm filtered by job number *(sounds so simple!)*

```
Private Sub Command50_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim ActvJbNum As Long
Dim pd As Long


ActvJbNum = Me.EntJobNum
pd = SumOfOpleadTm

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT Sum(tblRouting.OpleadTm) AS SumOfOpleadTm, tblRouting.[Job Number] " & vbCrLf & _
"FROM tblRouting " & vbCrLf & _
"GROUP BY tblRouting.[Job Number] " & vbCrLf & _
"HAVING(tblRouting.[Job Number])= """ & EntJobNum & """"

db.Execute strSQL

MsgBox ("pd")

End Sub
```

I keep getting a run time error saying 'Cannot execute a select query' any idea whats causing it?

Comment: You cannot call `Execute` on SELECT queries, only on action queries (insert, update etc). You need to open a recordset and read the values. Also a space is needed in `HAVING (...)`.

Comment: Also, if [Job Number] is of type text, you need to use ' (single quote) as delimiter.  Not the " (double quote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [DSum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dsum) to get the total `OpleadTm` for your target `[Job Number]`.

```vb
Private Sub Command50_Click()
    Dim pd As Long
    pd = DSum("OpleadTm", "tblRouting", "[Job Number]=" & Me.EntJobNum)
    MsgBox "pd: " & pd
End Sub
```

You can get what you want with much less code.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic of assigning pd as the resultant value of query is flawed...

Instead of using CurrentDb, you can use the following (assuming you have corrected your SQL):

```
pd = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute(strSQL).Fields("SumOfOpleadTm")
```

Comment: Hi exception, I've updated with the above line and added the space Kostas suggested and now get a 'data type mismatch in criteria expression' error the [OpleadTm] field is a number and so is the job number

Comment: If [Job Number] is a number field, then you can't use a string delimiter.  Change """ & EntJobNum & """"  --->  " & EntJobNum